# My expo client LAN QR code keeps loading up an old project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am running a new React-Native project through Visual Studio, but the LAN QR code in expo just opens an old project. The tunnel QR code links me to the correct project, but it is so incredibly slow that it is impossible to develop anything using it. I have tried deleting the cache on my phone, but this did not work. Yesterday, I was working on the project in a different location and it opened fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Completely closed the app down and then deleted the data and cache for the app in settings. Rescanned the QR code and this fixed it.